# How to narrow an array for a specific condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
results = [
  {"Created Date ": "20181012", "Created By ": "A", "Job Number ": "001", "Department": "FS"},
  {"Created Date ": "20181012", "Created By ": "B", "Job Number ": "002", "Department": "DS"},
  {"Created Date ": "20181012", "Created By ": "C", "Job Number ": "004", "Department": "FS"}
]
```

Each value will like below sometime.(without blank char and column order changed, but the column name is fixed)

```
results = [
  {"Created By": "A", "Department": "FS", "Created Date": "20181012", "Job Number": "001" },
  {"Created By": "B", "Department": "DS", "Created Date": "20181012", "Job Number": "002"},
  {"Created By": "C", "Department": "FS", "Created Date": "20181012", "Job Number": "004"}
]
```

Now, I only want to get a new array that contains the value of 3 columns, "Created By", "Created Date", and "Job Number", with a specific order.  The expected value should like:

```
results = [
  {"20181012", "A", "001"},
  {"20181012", "B", "002"},
  {"20181012", "C", "004"}
]
```

Is there any good solution?

Comment: if property name is fixed then you can use the `.map` to get what you want property order doesn't matter in object while you accessing them.

Comment: I have tried to results.map(({ 'Created Date ': created, 'Created By ': creator, 'Job Number ': tracknum }) => ({ created, creator, tracknum })), but it did not work for the array with blank value in the key.  {"Created Date ": "20181012", "Created By ": "A", "Job Number ": "001",....} @coder-of-coder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that objects don't have reliable ordering. So first or second column doesn't make any sense.

But since you know the keys for which you want the value, you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and at the same time account for the extra char by considering both variations of the key:

```js
var results = [{
    "Created Date ": "20181012",
    "Created By ": "A",
    "Job Number ": "001",
    "Department": "FS"
  },
  {
    "Created Date": "20181012",
    "Created By ": "B",
    "Job Number ": "002",
    "Department": "DS"
  },
  {
    "Created Date": "20181012",
    "Created By ": "C",
    "Job Number ": "004",
    "Department": "FS"
  }
]

var output = results.map(d => [
  d['Created Date'] || d['Created Date '],
  d['Created By'] || d['Created By '],
  d['Job Number'] || d['Job Number ']
]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @silder append a question. If I want to remove the null/blank value while looping in the map(), I tried operation ? : e.g.var output = results.map(d => d['Tracking Number'] && d['Created Date'] ? [
  d['Created Date'],  d['Job Number'] ] : '' );  still have to use another method to remove the blank item. Is it prossible to handle in map()?

Comment: @Ian You'll have to use `filter` for that. `filter` the blank values first and then use `map`.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates another way one might use an Array object's map() method, as follows:

```js
var results = [{
"Created Date ": "20181012",
"Created By ": "A",
"Job Number ": "001",
"Department": "FS"
  },
  {
"Created Date": "20181012",
"Created By": "B",
"Job Number": "002",
"Department": "DS"
  },
  {
" Created Date": "20181012",
" Created By": "C",
" Job Number": "004",
"Department": "FS"
  }
];

Array.prototype.remove = function(index){
  this.splice(index,1);
}

var nu_arry = results.map(item => {
  let d = [];
  let keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.remove(3);  // remove Department key name
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    d.push(item[key]);
  });
  return d;
});
console.log(nu_arry);
```

Whether a space occurs or not prior to or at the end of a key name makes scant difference because the code is able to detect precisely the names of all the keys by utilizing [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).  The advantage of this solution is that if ever a coder decided to modify the names of the keys, this code would still work, since there is no hard-coding of the variant keys. Note: the [short arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax obviates the need to create a separate user-defined function.